# Error in importing Keras sequential model

Tags: python, keras

I have installed keras followed by tensorflow. When I execute keras sequential model, I get an error message stating that

```
    from keras.models import sequential
    Using TensorFlow backend.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: cannot import name 'sequential'
```

Comment: try Sequential with capital S

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your post to include the code and maybe some sample data. Otherwise this is a shot in the dark! For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I should be `from keras.models import Sequential` . `Sequential` with an capital `S`

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply

Answer (score 1):

Changing my comment to the answer.

Try `Sequential` with capital S

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the lower case  **s** in **S**equential when you imported it. It should have been -  from `keras.models import Sequential`.However, as a side note, you can use the code `from tensorflow.keras import Sequential`, using the tensorflow keras api . If you are using colab, you can write `%tensorflow_version 2.x` at the beginning of your notebook to use version 2 of tensorflow

Comment: I just want to emphasize switching to `from tensorflow.keras import Sequential` fixed similar ~"Keras Sequential not found" type error for me.